# jquery handle keypress for list

Tags: jquery, list, keypress

I have a list like:

```
<div id="txt"></div>
<ul><li><a href="#">Tom</a></li><li><a href="#">Tina</a></li><li><a href="#">Berba</a></li><li><a href="#">Tyson</a></li><li><a href="#">Bank</a></li></ul>
```

my goal is: when i press a key like "T" and "Tom" will appear in #txt, and press "T" once more time, Tina will replace Tom in #txt.

I can't find a solution for this!!! :(

Someone can help me? Thanks

Comment: actualy what u need . Is that autocompletetion or something other ??? Please give a clear idea

Comment: something like autocompletetion!!!

Answer (score 1):

Listen keydown event, get keycode, get target name set , loop name. 
It may like this

```
var lastchar, i=-1;
$(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
  var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which),
      names = $('li a').filter(function(){
        return $(this).text().charAt(0)==char;
      });
  if( !names.length ){ return; }

  if( char != lastchar ){ i=-1; }
  $('#txt').text( names.eq( ++i % names.length ) );
});
```